# Which API key is needed to use Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the link I'm trying to access:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true
```

According to some documentation on Google.com, it doesn't look like an API key is needed for their Maps service anymore.  Can anyone see why the link I posted above wouldn't work?

If it does need an API key, could someone specific which API key is needed from Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should add a key

> Required parameters
>
> - query — The text string on which to search, for example: "restaurant". The Place service will return candidate matches based on this string and order the results based on their perceived relevance.
> - key — Your application's API key. This key identifies your application for purposes of quota management and so that Places added from your application are made immediately available to your app. Visit the APIs Console to create an API Project and obtain your key.
> - sensor — Indicates whether or not the Place request came from a device using a location sensor (e.g. a GPS) to determine the location sent in this request. This value must be either true or false.
>
> https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Some of their APIs to not require keys with each request, but you must still authenticate. From their developer docs:

> All Maps API applications* should load the Maps API using an API key.

You can read about the different APIs and their requirements [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).